# Subroutine, without using pow, and with parameter and return

Tags: c++, parameters, return, subroutine, pow

i don't understand what is wrong with my code it needs to have parameters and return, in c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int p(int,int);

int main() {
  int a,b,c;
  scanf("%d",&a);
  scanf("%d",&b);
  printf("%d\n",c);
  return 0;
}

int p(int a,int b){
  int t,i,c=1;
  for(i=1;i<=b;i++){
    t=a;
    c=c*t;
    return t;
  }
}
```

here's the input:
2
4

the output:
16

Comment: where are you calling to your function?

Comment: also, there isn't one thing in the code to make it c++ and not c so maybe you need to update the tag, and also don't use [#include<bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: The `c` in `main`and the `c` in `p` are different variables. Also, `return t;` is the same as `return a;`, since they always have the same value. That is, you have the equivalent of `int p(int a, int b) { return a;}`, but with undefined behaviour if `b` is less than 1.

Comment: Actually i made the changes jonh made, and put return c; and worked fine, anyway, thanks for your informations guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you meant to write this code

```
int p(int a,int b){
  int t,i,c=1;
  for(i=1;i<=b;i++){
    t=a;
    c=c*t;
  }
  return t;
}
```

In your version the `return` statement is inside the `for` loop.

And as has been pointed out, you probably meant this

```
printf("%d\n",p(a,b));
```

instead of this

```
printf("%d\n",c);
```

Comment: Thank you very much john, you helped me a lot, i also changed return t, to return c, and it worked.

Comment: @shioares Yes, sorry I missed that.